# Implement IntoIterator for struct which iterate its HashMap attribute

Tags: rust

I have a struct with an attribute of type `HashMap`. I want to implement the `IntoIterator` trait for this struct so that I can iterate its `HashMap` attribute. The problem is I run into lifetime hell:

```
pub struct ProcessList {
    map: HashMap<ProcessPtr, usize>,
}

impl ProcessList {
    pub fn new() -> ProcessList {
        ProcessList {
            map: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add(self, process: ProcessPtr, nb: usize) {
        match self.map.contain_key(process) {
            true => self.map[process] += nb,
            false => self.map.insert(process, nb),
        };
    }
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for ProcessList {
    type Item = (&'a ProcessPtr, &'a usize);
    type IntoIter = Iter<'a, ProcessPtr, usize>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.map.into_iter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide working [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) on [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4770e1f469415a3a66c4&version=stable) next time. This saves a lot of time for those who will respond to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See how `IntoIterator` implemented for `HashMap` in stdlib [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html#1366-1422)

If you want implement `IntoIterator` for `ProcessList` you do not need references and lifetimes at all:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::IntoIter;

#[derive(Eq,PartialEq,Hash)]
pub struct ProcessPtr;

pub struct ProcessList {
    map: HashMap<ProcessPtr, usize>,
}

impl ProcessList {
    pub fn new() -> ProcessList {
        ProcessList {
            map: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add(self, process: ProcessPtr, nb: usize) {
    /* Bunch of errors here
        match self.map.contains_key(process) {
            true => self.map[process] += nb,
            false => self.map.insert(process, nb),
        };
    */
    }
}

impl IntoIterator for ProcessList {
    type Item = (ProcessPtr, usize);
    type IntoIter = IntoIter<ProcessPtr, usize>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.map.into_iter()
    }
}

fn main(){
}
```

Also your code contains some errors in the `add` function.

Comment: WARNING: Per the [HashMap::into_iter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) documentation, "The map cannot be used after calling this". In which case, it seems you would have to deal with the lifetimes.

Answer (score 1):

### Borrowed based iterators vs owned iterators

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685608/2110869) by @aSpex, is an owned iterator implementation which means that elements are removed (or consumed) from the map as you iterate through it, which doesn't seem to be the requirements of the OP (see my comment for more info). [Aloso's blog post](https://aloso.github.io/2021/03/09/creating-an-iterator#implementing-the-iterator-trait) is a good read on this topic.

By correctly implementing the lifetimes below, we can avoid this consumption of the map:

```rust
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a ProcessList {
    type Item = (&'a ProcessPtr, &'a usize);
    type IntoIter = hash_map::Iter<'a, ProcessPtr, usize>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> hash_map::Iter<'a, ProcessPtr, usize> {
        self.map.iter()
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like with a for loop. Notice that we can now borrow `&my_process_list` with the `&`, preventing the consumption.

```rust
fn main() {
    // --snip--

// These are now; Notice the
// &references  ; borrow
//        /\      | 
//       v  v     v
    for (k, v) in &my_process_list {
        println!("({k}, {v})");
    }
    // Yay! It still has my data:
    assert!(original_count == my_process_list.into_iter().count());
    assert!(original_count == my_process_list.into_iter().count());
}
```